# Azure Event hub C# batch sender

Tags: azure-eventhub

Is there an option to send event in batch to Event hub from C#.
the [SendBatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubClient_SendBatch_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventData__) API mentioned doesn't exist in new EventHubClient.

Answer (score 1):

There is no longer a send batch call, but there is a SendAsync method with an IEnumerable overload that is effectively the same thing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.eventhubclient#Microsoft_Azure_EventHubs_EventHubClient_SendAsync_Microsoft_Azure_EventHubs_EventData_